# How to create two different types of registered users?

Tags: user, user-groups, registration, access

I have two sub user groups of **Registered** user group on my Joomla site.

`1. Present Students` and
`2. Ex-Students`

I want some modules to be shown to the `present students` only but I can only set access to the parent **Registered group** which makes it visible for both sub-groups. I googled about it, but couldn't find any proper solution. I read somewhere I need to play with the **Special** access level couldn't figure out how.

> What would be the most efficient way to achieve this?

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should be able to do this through Joomla's Access Levels.

In the backend, go to:

- **Users** (*top menu*) >> **Access Levels** >> **New**
- Create a different access level for **each** sub-usergroup.

Once done, go back to your module setting and you should be able to set the access level to one that you created.

Comment: @Saibbyweb - You're welcome :)